# How to prevent deleting indexedDB and cached files on close of the browser?

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am new to PWA. I am supposed to build a PWA, which should work in both offline mode and online mode. I am storing my data in indexedDB to work with it in offline mode. When I am closing the browser the indexedDB gets deleted, is there a way to prevent it? Also on closing the browser all the cached files are deleted as well, is there a way to prevent that. I dont want to use localStorage as I need to store blobs in offline mode.

Thanks

Comment: You can't prevent the user from deleting their data, from their web browser (because it is their web browser).
There are no local databases to which that rule does not apply.

If you want to protect against accidental deletion of data: Sync it to a user account on your server.

Comment: What you are looking for is called "persistent storage"

Comment: Look at this question and see if it helps you any: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55403450/3935060

Comment: Thank you all, yes I didnt know about persistent storage. This is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

As others said, you can not expect for any data to be around. Heck, **the user may even decide to uninstall the browser** with which your PWA was installed with.

- If you really need some data permanently tied to an user, you will need a login and server side storage.

That said:

- For small amounts of data (some kB only), I have encountered no problems with [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), it never got purged in the past
- For larger data (>100MB) I use the [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB) and I regularly experience purges. (My users will then reload the data from their file system, it ok)

The above applies for any modern browser, on any OS I encountered so far.